# Get number of visible select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select that looks like this:

```
<select id="days">
<option value="nothing">Select day</option>
<option value="monday2">Monday</option>
<option value="tuesday2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="wednesday2">Wednesday</option>
<option value="thursday2">Thursday</option>
<option value="friday2">Friday</option>
<option value="saturday2">Saturday</option>
<option value="sunday2">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

I want to know how many of the options in the select days are visible. The reason to this is because I have a function that may hide some of these options

I've tried something like this but it didnt work:

```
visibleoptions = $("days option:visible").index()+1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: hinding options doesnot work in IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is malformed, it should be prefixed with a hash sign. With a fixed selector, you only have to use the [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
var visibleCount = $("#days option:visible").length;
```

Comment: That only gives me the result 0. Even though there are 7 options visible.

Comment: @Henrik, that's strange, `:visible` and `length` always work properly in my experience. Are you sure there is no other element in your page with the id `days`?

Comment: Yeah I just doublechecked. I only have that single element with that id and there are 7 visible options within it.

Comment: @Henrik, what does `$("#days option:hidden").length` return?

Comment: That gave the result 8 which is weird. Since 8 is the amount of visible options. How does that work?

Comment: @Henrik, something is amiss here. Are there seven or eight visible options? Can you reproduce this problem on several (preferably non-IE) browsers?

Comment: Firefox gives the result 0 when I use option:hidden and the result 8 when i use option:visible.
And chrome does vice versa (result 8 at option:hidden).

Comment: @Henrik, confirmed, Chrome always considers `<option>` elements as hidden. It might be a bug in Chrome, or a bug in jQuery. In any case, since IE also does not reliably support hiding options, maybe you will want to try another strategy (removing them, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property

```
$("#days option:visible").length
```

Comment: @techfoobar The pseudo selector specified as `if they consume space in the document`this means at least one pixel. At least one pixel includes the next element, the length is generous. length+1 is wrong because it means the elemeht that is not even one pixel visible, thats why `length` is correct and thats why the edit to length without +1.